# No module named 'fuzzy_expert.fuzzy_system'

Tags: python

I'm using Google colab to build a Fuzzy-Expert model, where I install the required library package and import the necessary modules where the important library:

```
pip install fuzzy_expert
```

!pip install matplotlib-venn
!apt-get -qq install -y libfluidsynth1
!apt-get -qq install -y libarchive-dev && pip install -U libarchive
!apt-get -qq install -y graphviz && pip install pydot
!pip install cartopy

and import the necessary modules:

'''

```
import libarchive
import pydot
import cartopy
```

'''

and I got an error (No module named 'fuzzy_expert.fuzzy_system') when I run the code

'''

```
from fuzzy_expert.fuzzy_system import FuzzySystem
from fuzzy_expert.fuzzy_variable import FuzzyVariable
from fuzzy_expert.fuzzy_rule import FuzzyRule
```

'''

I used the examples suggested by the google colab platform but got the same error.

Comment: Verify two things. 1. That you in case you have two python versions, that the pip installer you used was for the version you are calling the import modules from. 2. Verify if pip did actually install the file by typing python at the terminal and then trying to import the module from there to see what happens